# Visual studio 2017 unable to update, installer uninstall with error log

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm facing as issue where i can not do anything with my VS 2017 installer, it happened that I tried to updated via auto update but it was unsuccessful then , i close the program then reopen it again, but now it wont be able to do anything, i try to use clean up tool from Github but still fail.. follow the MS instruction but also fail

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues

Below is my error log

> [0914:0009][2017-08-30T14:59:35] Error 0x80070057:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraphCore(IPackage
>   root, IEnumerable`1 packages, DependencyComparer comparer,
>   Dictionary`2 packageIndex, Dictionary`2 nodeIndex, Boolean splitNodes,
>   DependencyCollection deprecated)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Dependencies.DependencyManager.BuildGraph(IPackage
>   root, IEnumerable`1 packages, Boolean isUpdate,
>   IDependencyComparisonSeed seed, DependencyCollection deprecated)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.GetDependencyGraph(Product
>   product)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.PreChecks(String
>   installationPath, Boolean isLayoutSet, Product product, ExecuteAction
>   bootstrapperAction, ITelemetryOperation operation, IQuery query)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Uninstall(CancellationToken
>   token)The root node
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community,version=15.0.26430.16" is
>   not in the package collection. Parameter name: root`

Thank you so much in advance for every answer, really appreciate all help, 
best regards

Comment: Maybe check the activity log file and [edit] your question with anything interesting in it.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply i did DevEnv /ResetSettings and it seem to be ok now, thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error for 0x80070057 in the OS Header files is:

> An argument does not meet the contract of the method.

```
  DDERR_INVALIDPARAMS                                           ddraw.h        
  DIERR_INVALIDPARAM                                            dinput.h       
  DPERR_INVALIDPARAM                                            dplay.h        
  DPERR_INVALIDPARAMS                                           dplay.h        
  DPNERR_INVALIDPARAM                                           dplay8.h       
  DSERR_INVALIDPARAM                                            dsound.h       
  DVERR_INVALIDPARAM                                            dvoice.h       
  ecInvalidParam                                                ec.h           
  ecInvalidSession                                              ec.h           
  ecBadBuffer                                                   ec.h           
  MAPI_E_INVALID_PARAMETER                                      mapicode.h     
  STIERR_INVALID_PARAM                                          stierr.h       
  E_INVALIDARG                                                  winerror.h
```

> Some problem with an invalid parameter. Based on this try and do a [/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx)

```
DevEnv /ResetSettings
```

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273.aspx

---

Failing that you should:

1. Uninstall VS2017.
2. Use a tool called MSIZap/[msicuu2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx) to remove any left overs.
3. Reinstall.

---

Failing that you have little choice but to rebuild your PC.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answer but i follow DevEnv /ResetSettings and now i'm able to update it once again, =D thanks so much for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting Visual Studio 2017 installation and upgrade issues

See this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues)